# Marker tint makes it too dark on Google Maps iOS

Tags: android, ios, swift, google-maps

When I create a marker and add it to the maps (using Google maps) the tint makes it too dark, compared to Android.

Here is how it looks:

[image]

And on Android it looks fine:

[image]

Both using the same colour.

Here's full iOS code:

```
import UIKit
import GoogleMaps
import MapKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: GMSMapView!
    let color = UIColor(red: 254 / 255.0, green: 247 / 255.0, blue: 120 / 255.0, alpha: 1)
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        mapView.animate(to: GMSCameraPosition(latitude: 53.141214, longitude: 17.957853, zoom: 15))
        addRoute()
        addMarker()
    }
    
    func addRoute() {
        let path = GMSMutablePath()
        path.add(CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 53.141546, longitude: 17.955096))
        path.add(CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 53.141088, longitude: 17.958740))
        let polyline = GMSPolyline(path: path)
        polyline.strokeColor = color
        polyline.strokeWidth = 5
        polyline.map = mapView
    }
    
    func addMarker() {
        let marker = GMSMarker()
        marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 53.141214, longitude: 17.957853)
        marker.icon = GMSMarker.markerImage(with: color)
        marker.map = mapView
    }

}
```

To make this answer full and easy to test, I'm providing example project you can test out:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1StUxLzPldMhcMX4dmuGfy89Bbv9h5Cus/view?usp=sharing

Only thing needed is to replace google maps api key with yours.

edit:

I'm aware I can use custom image. I want to use the default marker image and just find the way to modify the colour to match Android look.

Comment: Google Maps SDK for iOS is a different thing from Google Maps SDK for Android. It is only natural that there are differences. If you need the same image, create the same image yourself and use it.

Comment: I know these are 2 separate SDKs, yet nearly similar. I want to provide the same experience, so the same images are needed. Tint is probably working different on iOS, but there should be a way to modify the colour to match android look.

Comment: You may want to add an entry in [Google Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=188833&template=789005) to check if this is an issue with the SDK.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Define color like following line.. I don't know if it will fix your problem. but in my case, it worked(funny way).

```
 let color = UIColor(red: 254.0/255.0, green: 247.0/255.0, blue: 120.0/ 255.0, alpha: 1)
```

Comment: It's almost the same line I provided. The only difference is ".0" after number (before division), which doesn't really matter as floating division is guaranteed by second number (255.0).

Comment: I don't know why but in my case it worked. Even i was astonished. you can try.

Comment: Just tried. No difference if it's 254 or 254.0